# Laravel 4 with HTML5 History

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade, html5-history

How can I utilize HTML5 history with Laravel 4? Here is my blade content file:

```
@extends('main')

@section('content')
   This is content.
@endsection
```

I was thinking to only load the content part in HTML5 history by putting:

```
@if($showMain)
@extends('main')
@endif
```

But it doesn't work. The `@extends` has to be the very first line of the file. I was thinking of putting a few `@if($showMain)` in the main file. But this way will make the code messy and less maintainable. So, how can I archive that with a cleaner way in Laravel blade? Or, is there a better way to do HTML5 history with Laravel?

Thanks.

Comment: `I was thinking to only load the content part in HTML5 history`, what does that mean ? Can you elaborate ? Confused about `HTML5 history`.

Comment: When user click on new link or go back to previous page, only the change part of website which is the content area will be loaded from server. All the other part remains on the browser without being reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

History can only be accessed via client-side Javascript code, so there's no way to access that in Laravel which is run server-side.

What you can do though is keep track of the page history on the server's side using sessions.

Comment: Yeah I know that. So, I am thinking to use JavaScript to pass special parameter in the URL. Then, server will know and only return the page with content area only.

Comment: Thanks. I will not downvote anyone who try to help. I personally think that the downvote system here is being abuse by many people. There are many time people just downvote you just because they think you are asking silly question.